# Why won't Ubuntu use my ethernet cable?

Tags: 12.04, internet, connection, ethernet

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and for some reason, Ubuntu will *not* use an Ethernet cord.
It will recognize it and say that I have a connection, but it won't access the internet through it. I plan to use Ethernet to upgrade, as it is a more steady connection with better speeds than my Wireless, and it worked before...Why won't it work now?

The WiFi works great, stays connected better than Windows, but when I plug in the Ethernet, kaput. No more internet. It won't connect again unless I unplug the Ethernet cord. ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove your `Wired connection` and remake it. I think you might have some problems with your [route](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/route.8.html).

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry, I'm rather new to Linux system administration

Comment: From top panel, `network menu` > `Edit connections` > `Wired`; Select your current connection and remove it. Then add another one.

Comment: Well, that appears to have done something... I erased the profile for the Ethernet, then I plugged it in again. The usual problem came up (with both going, no internet) so I disabled the Wireless via the hardware switch and set the Ethernet to Auto Ethernet. Only thing is, I have to continually click on the Auto Ethernet option to get it to stay...

Comment: Wierd...Unity does a WAY better job of getting good speeds out of the Ethernet than GNOME Classic ??? Anyways, thanks! That seems to have fixed it!

Comment: I think unity has become stable enough to make it your default desktop manager ;) But there is no difference between Unity network manager and Gnome classic's.

Comment: Unity and Gnome use *exactly* the same networking stack.